# Querying database using geographical areas/points

Tags: gis, geospatial, spatial

I'm new to the concept of GIS in databases and am looking for a solution that allows me to do the following:
- store polygon areas in a record field
- Store geographical points. These points will contain latitude and longitude coordinates (GPS).
- query database for all records, whose polygons intersect with a given point. 
- query database for all records, whose points intersect with a given area

Any recommendations?

thanks,

Fbr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [PostGreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/) with the [PostGIS](http://postgis.refractions.net/) extension. Free open source, very mature.
- [SQL Server](http://www.microsoft.com/SQL) 2008 has built-in [Spatial Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933876.aspx). Even in the free Express Edition.
- [Oracle](http://www.oracledatabase11g.com)
- [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com) 5.6.1 or later has built-in spatial extensions.

More information [here on different spatial databases](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90/what-are-the-best-databases-for-storing-spatial-data-pros-and-cons) and [here on learning about spatial databases](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10376/spatial-databases-learning-resources-for-newbies)